# Issue with CSS Peek in VSCode

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I downloaded and enabled the CSS Peek extension, but it doesn't actively update. If I add a HTML element and a corresponding CSS style in separate files, CSS Peek doesn't automatically match the definition mapping. It's not until I reload my files does the "Go to Definition" right-click option work. Any ideas on how to fix this? (I'm using the current version of VSCode)

Answer (score 5):

Author here. This is fixed in the latest version of CSS Peek (4.0.0)

Comment: same issue :-).

Comment: Hey there everyone. It wasn't working for me as well (v4.2.2). I uninstalled and installed it again, and works for me. (Mac user here).

Comment: There were a few bugs causing this issue to continue happening - please update to v4.3.5 (released yesterday) which should fix all the pending issues here